# Build up correct form Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui, cmis

I am attempting to preform File Upload with Kendo UI.  The file is stored in an ECM which I upload to with CMIS utilizing Browser Binding.  My original AJAX function which is working is like:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'MY CMIS URL',
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData($('#myForm')[0]),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function () {
            alert("Document Uploaded");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
        }
    });
```

So my form has CMIS properties on it - this successfully gets added to my Request when I look at fiddler - as shown:

[image]

However now I am using Kendo UI for upload and the code is as below:

```
    $("#target").kendoUpload({
        multiple: false,
        async: {
            saveUrl: 'MY CMIS URL',
            autoUpload: true,
            withCredentials: false,
        },
        upload: function (e) {
            $('#propertyValue_0_').val(e.files[0].name);
           // e.data = new FormData($('#uploadForm')[0]); - did not work
            var formData = $('#uploadForm').serializeArray();
            e.data = formData;
        }
    });
```

First I had the data set similar to my AJAX call but this did not work.  Doing a serialize and setting e.data = formData; is closer to what I need.  When I check the fiddler request I see the below:

[image]

If I set a breakpoint in Dev Tools I can see that formData variable contains the array of objects with the name and value as "cmisaction" "createDocument"

[image]
 and the same for the rest of the propeties but instead in my fiddler trace I am geting name="0" and [Object Object] sent.

How can I correctly set e.data to the name and values in formData?